# PMPI_COMM_RANK Invalid Communicator

Tags: c++, mpi

So I am a complete novice at MPI but I've inherited code that uses it. The script contains a section that processes a data file and uses the MPI_COMM_RANK routine:

```
/* Load Data */
std::cout << "Loading data..." << std::endl;
ThisTask=0;
All.ICFormat=1;
RestartFlag=1;
/* This is actually an MPI routine, so we will need to set up MPI */
NTask=1; /* Gadget2 global */
All.PartAllocFactor=1.0; /* The factor for allocating memory for particle   data. */
All.BufferSize = 1024.0; /* The size (in MByte per processor) of a communication buffer. */
if(!(CommBuffer = malloc(All.BufferSize * 1024 * 1024))) {
printf("failed to allocate memory for `CommBuffer' (%i MB).\n", All.BufferSize);
return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &ThisTask);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &NTask);
read_file(fname, readTask, lastTask);
free(CommBuffer);
MPI_Finalize();     /* clean up & finalize MPI */
std::cout << "...done" << std::endl;
```

However, Comm rank returns the error:

```
Fatal error in PMPI_Comm_rank: Invalid communicator, error stack:
PMPI_Comm_rank(122): MPI_Comm_rank(comm=0x629300, rank=0x631eec) failed
PMPI_Comm_rank(75).: Invalid communicator
```

Again, as I'm totally new to this I have no idea why COMM_WORLD would be an invalid communicator here. Any ideas?

Comment: This usually indicates that some sort of a mix-up between various MPI implementations or different versions of the same MPI implementation has occurred. E.g. `mpi.h` is from one version while the binary library files are from another one. Or the code was linked against one version but then the runtime environment provides a different one. Make sure that `mpicc` / `mpic++` / `mpiCC` are from the same MPI implementation as `mpirun` / `mpiexec` used to launch the executable.

Comment: not a question you asked, so i'm leaving it as a comment, but you might want to look into MPI-IO for (and pass a communicator to) your read_file routine.

Comment: I would definely try to run some pre-made MPI example there are on the net, to be sure that the code hasn't any subtle typo. So you can rule out some compile problems

Comment: In my case, it was because `conda init` interfered with the `I_MPI_ROOT` environment variable set for Intel MPI (and possibly other related things). The solution was to initialize Intel MPI environment variables after `conda init`.