# Fatal error in PMPI_Comm_rank: Invalid communicator

Tags: fortran, mpi, mpich

```
program main
  use mpi
  character * (MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME) processor_name 
  integer myid, numprocs, namelen, rc, ierr
  integer comm
  call MPI_INIT( ierr )
  call MPI_COMM_RANK( comm, myid, ierr )
  call MPI_COMM_SIZE( comm, numprocs, ierr )
  call MPI_GET_PROCESSOR_NAME(processor_name, namelen, ierr)
  write(*,*) "Hello World! Process ",myid," of ", numprocs, " on ", processor_name
  call MPI_FINALIZE(rc)
end program main
```

This is an example from a textbook. But the original one use `MPI_COMM_WORLD` to replace the `comm` in `MPI_COMM_RANK` and `MPI_COMM_SIZE`. I did this change only because I find that the prototype says `comm` should be an integer. After I did this change, I use `mpifort test_mpi.f90` to compile and create `a.out` file. Next I use `mpirun -n 4 ./a.out` to execute it, it shows the following error.

> Fatal error in PMPI_Comm_rank: Invalid communicator, error stack:
>   PMPI_Comm_rank(110): MPI_Comm_rank(comm=0x0, rank=0x7ffd9b870564)
>   failed PMPI_Comm_rank(68).: Invalid communicator

I did some search on the SO, and find someone said that [mpi.h is from one version while the binary library files are from another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33176592/pmpi-comm-rank-invalid-communicator). But I only install once mpich and never use mpi before. So what's the problem here?

Answer (score 2):

Your variable `comm` has never been initialized and has an undefined value.

You must give it a value. At the start, the global communicator is `MPI_COMM_WORLD`.

```
comm = MPI_COMM_WORLD
```

Of course, `MPI_COMM_WORLD` is integer too, it is an integer constant.

Comment: Can I assign comm to some other value except for MPI_COMM_WORLD?

Comment: No. Not before you create a different communicator, but you must first learn how and why to do that. Learn basic MPI first.

Comment: if possible, you'd rather use the Fortran 2008 bindings instead since they are way less error-prone. for example a communicator has type `TYPE(MPI_Comm)`.

Comment: It is not enough supported by compilers (gfortran). At least for my purposes.

Comment: which gfortran and MPI are you using ? iirc, there is enough support in gfortran 4.9.2 for Open MPI, but for MPICH, only ifort and cray compilers can compile Fortran 2008 bindings.

Comment: I use multiple computers and I cannot rely on one version on one computer.